# Vue and Laravel: Delete item by ID

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to delete item by passing data.id through vue js to laravel in backend. Below is the code but its returning 500 Internal Server Error.

```
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-danger mt-2" href="#" @click.prevent="destroy(data)">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
 </button>

destroy(data) {
            // Use can use this as the payload.
            axios.delete(`/delData/${data.id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.loadSharedData();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error.message);
                    this.error = 'Post couldnot be deleted!';
                })
        }
```

And the Controller in Laravel:

```
  public function destroy(Request $request, SharedData $delItem)
{
    $delItem->delete();
    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
```

And the Route:

```
 Route::delete('/delData/{sharedDataItem}', 'SharedDataController@destroy')->name('deleteSharedData');
```

I couldn't figure out whats wrong here.

Solution:
I did mistake in parameter name. Changed the parameter name in controller from $delItem to $sharedDataItem (which i used in the route). It worked.

```
   Previous: public function destroy(Request $request, SharedData $delItem)
   Now: public function destroy(Request $request, SharedData $sharedDataItem)
```

Comment: Nothing in Laravel's log file? What does your route look like?

Comment: Where is API route creation function?

Comment: I have update route above.

Comment: i don't see anything different then to how i do it. except instead of "axios.delete(`/delData/${data.id}`)" i do "axios.delete(`/delData/' + data.id`)" i dont think this is the solution you are looking for, but still trying to help :)

Comment: Please add the exception Laravel logged in the `storage/logs/laravel.log` to the question.

Comment: I found the error, i changed the parameter name in controller from $delItem to $sharedDataItem (which i used in the route). It worked.